# local variables, NSArray, EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on initWithObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some arrays that I only need in my .M file, so I thought that I declare them in the interface brackets like so in MyViewController.m ( by this I am making them private variables, in Java C# lingo)

```
   @interface MyViewController () {
    NSArray *myArray; 
   }
   @end

   @implementation FilterViewController
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // This line throws  an error
      myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2","3", @"4", nil];
```

Now the last line throws an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, and I don;t know why?

I am new to Objective C coming from C#.Net, I think what I did with my declaration is like declaring private variables, if thats incorrect I am eager to know the correct way of doing it.
Thanks.

Comment: You'd be surprised how often this happens. The suggestion to use array literals to get better error reporting is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you would use properties for something like this, but with ARC it wont matter.

But the problem you have here is with `"3"` instead of `@"3"`. "3" is an array of characters, while the @ is a literal which turns the array into an NSString. Since NSArray can only store objects, it crashes when you try to add a char*

Comment: you mean properties for private variables? so I declare them in the .H file and then synthesize in the .m file?

Answer (score 2):

Note that a better way to create the array would be to use the new "container literals":

```
myArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
```

Then the *compiler* would give an error message if you accidentally omit the `@`
(or generally if any of the collection elements is not an Objective-C object),
instead of your application crash at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this symbol **@** in this line. So you need to use this one **@"3"**.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple one, you've missed an `@` symbol before the `"3"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2",@"3", @"4", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you don't need to declare your private iVars in an extension, you could just put it straight in the implementation: e.g

```
@interface FilterViewController {
    NSArray *myArray; 
}
```

Although a better solution would be to use a property, which you do declare in the extension:

```
@interface FilterViewController () {
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray; 
}
@end

@implementation FilterViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myArray = @[@"1", @"2",@"3", @"4"];
}
```